# change the scale manually and legend labels to reflect intervals

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2, scale, legend

I have plotted a map in ggplot and used

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
states <- map_data("world")
test<-data.frame(Market=c("Fayzabad","Herat","Jalalabad","Kabul","Kandahar","Maymana","Mazar","Nili"),
             Country=rep("Afghanistan",8),lat=c(37.12144,34.34195,34.43419,34.52845,31.32000,35.92017,36.70000,33.72245),
             long=c(70.57852,62.20306,70.44768,69.17170,65.43000,64.77631,67.11667,66.12503),
             S=c(8.021731,9.002656,14.952483,9.201323,15.080901,15.009068,14.295761,6.217411),
             NC=c(2,3,3,5,3,2,6,9))


p <- ggplot()
p <- p + geom_polygon( data=states, aes(x=long, y=lat, group = group),fill="black",colour="white" )
p <- p + geom_point(data=test, aes(x=long, y=lat,color = S,size=NC))+
scale_color_gradient(low="yellow",high="red", limit=c(0,25),space="Lab",name = "Seasonality")+

scale_size(range = c(0, 10),name="Number of Commodities")+ggtitle("Seasonality Map")+theme_bw()
p
```

which plots nicely the points I want on the map and gives a legend. However I would like to change the legend of the plot and set the color and size scale manually so that color and size scale and the legend look like...

legend

```
NC
*small circle*  1-3
*medium circle* 4-6
*large circle*  7-9

S
*yellow color*  < 10
*orange color*  10-25
*red color*     25 <
```

I know there is a cut function, but i just wanted to know if you can do it using the scale options in ggplot without making new categorical variables.

Answer (score 2):

For the color you can use `scale_colour_gradientn` and provide your own colors and intervals like this :

```
scale_colour_gradientn(colours = c("yellow","orange","red"),
                     values=c(0,10,25,max(mapdf$S)))
```

For the size you should use  `scale_size_continuous(breaks=...)` but without a reproducible example I can't be sure.

Comment: there an extra n and missing ) but otherwise when i put in this command it gives me Error in continuous_scale("colour", "gradient", seq_gradient_pal(low,  : 
  unused arguments (colours = c("yellow", "orange", "red"), values = c(0, 10, 25, 149.209542480829))

Comment: extra n? just a missing `)` and I add it. The function is `scale_colour_gradientn` with "n" . And if you provide a reproducible example you will get a better quality answer. I can't test my answer since you don't provide any support to do it.

Comment: I apologize for the n as I didnt know about gradientn. I will edit the post with sample data so it can be reproduced

Comment: for some reason gradietn isnt working for me. If gives me the colors, but everything is yellow including in the legend

Comment: @BaconDoggie you question still not reproducible you should provide "states" data set also.